# Plotting specific range of values within an array Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I want to plot a certain range of values within 2 arrays using matplotlib,

```
seconds = 200
dt = .001
x = array of values
time = arange(0, seconds, dt)
```

Goal is to plot everything after the first 25 seconds. I Know I could create 2 new arrays using a for loop, but I'm certain there's some simple built in function for such things.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. writing

```
time[a:b]
```

will give you an array of all the values between time[a] and time[b].

Comment: you should accept your own answer.  Marking the question as answered helps both people looking for answers (as they know they will find a solution) and those looking to answer questions (as they know the question likely does not need more attention).